# Find all holomorphic diffeomorphisms $f:\mathbb{CP}^1\to\mathbb{CP}^1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, projective-geometry

The complex projective line $\mathbb{CP}^1$ is the complex manifold defined by the quotient of $\mathbb{C}^2-\{(0,0)\}$ by the relation $z\sim w$ if $z=\lambda w$ for $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$. I am trying to show that a map 
$$f:\mathbb{CP}^1\to\mathbb{CP}^1$$
is a (holomorphic) diffeomorphism if and only if $f$ is obtained from an invertible matrix $M\in\mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ by quotienting
$$M:\mathbb{C}^2-\{0\}\to\mathbb{C}^2-\{0\}.$$
I was able to show that every such $M$ indeed gives a diffeomorphism, but I am not able to prove the other direction. How show that every diffeomorphism arise in this way?

Comment: Some point $a$ goes to $\infty$. Multiply by $z-a$. The remaining function should be now nice at infinity (and everywhere), this forces it to be a polynomial. But it cant have many zeros. This forces it to be linear. This question for sure has been asked here before. You can use the search box to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $GL(2,\mathbb{C})$ acts transitively on $\mathbb{C}P^1$. Take a diffeomorphism $\phi$. Let $\phi ( \infty ) = \alpha$. Take $g\in GL(2,\mathbb{C})$ with $g(\alpha) = \infty$ 
( for instance $g(z) = \frac{1}{z-\alpha}$). Consider the diffeomorphism $\psi = g \circ \phi$. 
We have $\psi( \infty) = \infty$, $\psi(\mathbb{C}) \subset \mathbb{C}$ and $\lim_{z\to \infty}\psi(z) = \psi (\infty)= \infty$. Therefore, $\psi_{\mid \mathbb{C}}$ is entire with limit $\infty$ at $\infty$. Consider the power series expansion of $\psi$

$$\psi(z) = \sum_{n\ge 0} a_n z^n$$

Now introduce the coordinate $t= \frac{1}{z}$ around $\infty$ for the subset $\mathbb{C}\backslash \{0\}$ of the domain  $\mathbb{C}$. Then we have
the Laurent expansion on $\mathbb{C} \backslash\{0\}$:

$$\chi(t) \colon = \psi(\frac{1}{t}) = \sum_{n\ge 0} a_n t^{-n}$$.

Moreover, since $\lim_{t \to 0} \chi(t) = \infty$, $\chi$ cannot have an essential singularity at $0$  (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casorati%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) and so $0$ must be a pole so the Laurent expansion of $\chi $ terminates at some degree $-d$
$$\chi(t) = \sum_{n=0 }^{d} a_n t^{-n}$$
 That means that the power series expansion  of $\psi$ is finite and therefore $\psi$ itself is a polynomial of some degree $d$. 
with $a_d\ne 0$

$$\psi(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^d a_n z^n$$

Now for every $u \in \mathbb{C}$ the equation $\psi(z) = u$ will have $d$ roots in $\mathbb{C}$ ( with multiplicity) and for all but finitely many values $u$ it will have exactly $d$ roots ( we have to eliminate the $u$'s the values of the polynomial at the roots of its derivative). Since $\psi$ is also known to be injective we conclude that $d=1$ and therefore 
$$\psi(z) = a_0 + a_1 z$$

with $a_1 \ne 0$.

We showed that the  diffeomorphism $\psi$ of $\mathbb{C}P^1$ is given by $\psi(z) = a z + b $ for some $a$, $b \in \mathbb{C}$. Therefore  $\psi= g \circ \phi $ is given by a transformation from $GL(2,\mathbb{C})$, and therefore $\phi$ is.

Obs: We reduced the problem to the one of  finding the diffeomorphisms of $\mathbb{C}$.  In fact we can show that any holomorphic and injective map $\psi \colon \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ is of the form $\psi(z) = a z + b$. Let's prove first that $\psi$ is surjective. Note that any injective holomorphic map is open. Therefore, $\psi \colon \mathbb{C} \to \psi (\mathbb{C})$ is a homeomorphisms, and therefore the open subset $\psi (\mathbb{C})$ is simply connected. Assume that $\psi (\mathbb{C})$ is not $\mathbb{C}$. Then there exists a holomorphic diffeomorphism  $u$ from $\psi (\mathbb{C})$ to the unit disk. In fact, it is enough that the diffeomorphism maps $u$ $\psi (\mathbb{C})$ to a subset of the unit disk. But then $u \circ \psi$ is a non-constant and bounded holomorphic function, and therfore (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28complex_analysis%29) the function $u \circ \psi $ is constant, contradiction.

Therefore, an injective map $\psi$ from $\mathbb{C}$ to itself is a diffeomorphism. In particular, $\lim_{z \to \infty} \psi(z) = \infty$. We conclude like before that $\psi$ is a polynomial of degree $1$.

Comment: We reduced to finding the automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}$. Note that for every $N$ the automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}P^N$ are similarly described, while the automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}^N$ are more complicated.

Comment: The argument seems kind of sloppy when you get rid of the essential singularity. Where did you use the holomorphic condition at $0$ in $\mathbb{CP}^{1}$? You should write this more clearly.

Comment: @Bombyx mori: Yes, I see your point, the coordinate $t$ was for the domain, I will add that in the proof.

Comment: Perhaps I missed something, but I think it is suffice for you to use the bi-holomorphic condition given near infinity. If there is an essential singularity this would not work. And there is no need to appeal to Weierstrass–Casorati theorem.

Comment: @Bombyx mori: I think I see what you mean, $0$ is a removable singularity for $\frac{1}{\psi(1/t)}$  ( since $1/\psi(1/0) = 0$ , and therefore $1/\psi(1/t) = \sum_{n\ge 1} b_n t^n$. Now this series must have $b_1 \ne 0$ because of injectivity and we get $\psi(1/t) =1/t ( \sum_{n \ge 0} c_n t^n)$. Now compare with the expansion of $\psi(z)$. I agree that this is straightforward and avoids W-C. However, we should point out that this is the way to show $W-C$ - is: if $\psi$ at infinity stays away from $\beta$ then $1/(\psi - \beta)$ is bounded and therefore can be  extended at $\infty$.

Comment: @organgeskid: No, I meant something much more elementary. Let $\psi=g\circ \phi$ as you wrote be the bi-holomorphism. Then an essential singularity cannot exist anywhere, for any complex manifold, because we have assumed locally it is holomorphic via some suitable local coordinates. Is there some obvious mistake in my argument?

Comment: @Bombyx mori: It is quite OK, I see your point. Can I rephrase it like this? Look around $0$ for $\phi(z)$ and also for $1/\psi(1/t)$. Take their series expansions. Neat. No need to come from $\mathbb{C}$ only.

Comment: @organeskid: I do not have much more to comment (writing is not my strongest talent). But I suspect you meant $\psi$, not $\phi$. Anyway thanks for the conversation and your time.

Comment: @Bombyx mori: Uff, I should have had this on my mind. We can in fact show that any holomorphic map from $\mathbb{C}P^1$ to itself ( that is, a meromorphic function on $\mathbb{C}P^1$) is given by a rational function. Indeed: we can substract a rational function to eliminate all the polar parts. The result is a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}P^1$ that must be a constant. Yes, looking at the polar parts at all the poles is the key.

Comment: @organzeskid: I hope you realize that the fact that any holomorphic map from the Riemann sphere to itself has the same number of poles and zeros by Riemann-Hurwitz. And you are working with a bijective map, so you have only one zero and one pole. The rest should be obvious to you.